# What exactly does the term ?count= and &after= mean in a url

Tags: html, web, url, reddit

I am looking at the reddit url for a subreddit to gather data, and I am finding some strange terms in the url such as

> "https://www.reddit.com/r/ADHD/comments/?count=175&after=t1_ifdasae". The terms

> ?count=175&after=t1_ifdasae

specifically are bothering me. This is because when i click the button to go to the next page of answers, the count increments by 25 (e.g /count=200), but the &after= term changes to something similar, but seemingly random such as t1_ifd9h5bm, or then t1_ifd7w7w.

On the other hand, if the url is without the &after section, changing the count by 25 manually will sometimes change the page contents, but sometimes not at all. For example, 0 and 25 are the same for me, but 50 is different. 75 is the same as 50, then 100 is different again, but now screwing up the pattern 125 is back to the same as 25 and 50!

Testing some more, 100,200,300 and seemingly up to 9000 are the same, bu then 10000 is completely different, and 100000 is the same as 100 and 200 etc. Similar behaviour is seen when the count changes but the &after variable stays the same.

Does anyone know what on earth these variables mean, and more importantly, if there is a set way to change the url so that i get the next 25 comments each time?

Edit: After playing around with the after tag, that also for some reason isnt changing anything except loading the new posts no matter what i change it to.

Comment: `count=` is the page-size and `after` is a _paging anchor_ which keeps results stable when the source data will have entries added or removed in-between the time it takes you to load another page.  Most websites and applications don't use anchored-paging (because it's complicated to implement) and use traditional paging parameters:  `count` (aka `pageSize`) and `offset` (aka `pageIndex`).

Comment: Also see https://coderwall.com/p/lkcaag/pagination-you-re-probably-doing-it-wrong

Comment: "if there is a set way to change the url so that i get the next 25 comments each time?" - I have a better idea: instead of scraping reddit's HTML, just use their web-service API instead: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/

Comment: @Dai what do you mean by the page size? No matter what count is the same number of posts are loaded on the webpage.

Comment: You're right: Reddit does seem to completely ignore the `count` parameter - I could swear it used to work many years ago.

Comment: Thats interesting. Do you know why the posts shown would still sometimes change for different values then? Also, i know i could use the reddit api but i would like to do it manually for fun.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about software development.

Answer (score -1):

> What exactly does the term ?count= and &after= mean in a url

They could mean anything at all. It's up to the website that is giving you that URL and processing it when you click on it. The answers that you're getting are reddit-specific, but there's no reason that they will mean the same thing anywhere else.

One thing to note is that in `?count=175&after=t1_ifdasae`, the `?` means "the rest of the URL is parameters" and the `&` separates two parameters. There could be others, using the `&` as a separator.

Comment: Sorry i should have specified - what do they mean within reddits webpage? Also, there are no other visible parameters.